# How to vertically align images and text with display:inline-block?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an icon fit nicely between text in HTML/CSS.

It seems like this should be possible with `display:inline-block;`. However this always seems to go wrong due to *phantom padding*:

```
<div style="">
    <div style="display:inline-block;">Text here</div><img style="height:24px;display:inline-block" src="{{ url_for('static', filename= 'images/icon-unsorted.png' ) }}" />
</div>
```

[image]

As you can see the **outer div becomes 25.64px high**, while both its **child elements are 24px high**.

Moreover the image is aligned at the bottom, whereas the text is aligned to the top of the outer div.

I however want both of them to be vertically (center) aligned.

If i try to **force the outer div to 24px**: `<div style="height:24px;">`, contents remain incorrectly aligned, and the icon simply overflows below its parent.

[image]

So I suppose my question is this:

**How do i make an image fit nicely inside a line of text, where the image has the same height as the text, or both are center aligned vertically?**

Comment: Try putting the ```<img>``` inside the text's ```<div>```

Comment: to make two child aligned center in vertically you'd use display:flex rather than inline-block

Comment: Try forcing outer div height:24px and img max-height:100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might try a more css oriented approach. I made a small example below.

```css
.btnStyle {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 110px;
  height: 24px;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: black;
  background-image: url(https://extortionguild.com/images/icon-unsorted.png);
  background-size: 17.5px 100%;
  background-position: right center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

table {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  font-size: 18px;
}

table td {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:inline-block; width: 100% height: 40px;">

  <div class="btnStyle"><!-- Button 1-->
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Text here
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="btnStyle"><!-- Button 2-->
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Text here
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="btnStyle" style="width: 200px;"><!-- Button 3 - wider-->
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Even More Text here
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>
```

• Using classes will also allow you to make changes to all the buttons via the btnStyle class, instead of having to change each individually.

• Tables have a "built-in" vertical-align: middle; option and it's a really simple method of aligning any cell content centered vertically. -- [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

• You will need to edit background image url to background-image: url(images/icon-unsorted.png); to load your image file.

***[development-ninja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10741568/development-ninja)** was also on the right track with "flex", but it needs to be "inline-flex" or they will try to stack. -- For inline-flex browser support info click [here](https://caniuse.com/?search=display%3A%20inline-flex)*

Comment: Thank you for the response! In that documentation link you've send I found: `vertical-align: text-bottom;` That seems to work if the image is the same height as the text!